# How to Set a QA Mode Webpack/Webpack Serve?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a

webpack.common.js
webpack.dev.js
webpack.prod.js
webpack.qa.js

and each of the 3 environments I have set a mode

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const convert = require("koa-connect");
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const historyApiFallback = require("koa2-connect-history-api-fallback");

const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  // Provides process.env.NODE_ENV with value development.
  // Enables NamedChunksPlugin and NamedModulesPlugin.
  mode: "QA",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  // configure `webpack-serve` options here
  serve: {
    // The path, or array of paths, from which static content will be served.
    // Default: process.cwd()
    // see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve#options
    content: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    add: (app, middleware, options) => {
      // SPA are usually served through index.html so when the user refresh from another
      // location say /about, the server will fail to GET anything from /about. We use
      // HTML5 History API to change the requested location to the index we specified
      app.use(historyApiFallback());
      app.use(
        convert(
          // Although we are using HTML History API to redirect any sub-directory requests to index.html,
          // the server is still requesting resources like JavaScript in relative paths,
          // for example http://localhost:8080/users/main.js, therefore we need proxy to
          // redirect all non-html sub-directory requests back to base path too
          proxy(
            // if pathname matches RegEx and is GET
            (pathname, req) => pathname.match("/.*/") && req.method === "GET",
            {
              // options.target, required
              target: "http://localhost:8080",
              pathRewrite: {
                "^/.*/": "/" // rewrite back to base path
              }
            }
          )
        )
      );
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

then in my code I reference the mode by `process.env.NODE_ENV` but when I run my QA config I get

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.mode should be one of these:
   "development" | "production" | "none"
   -> Enable production optimizations or development hints.
```

How can I set more than these modes?

I am using webpack and [webpack serve](https://github.com/chobo2/webpack-serve-example)

Edit

in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-serve --config webpack.dev.js --open",
    "prod": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js",
    "qa": "cross-env NODE_ENV=QA webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
```

Then in one of my files I have

```
  console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV",process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set! There are only those 3 modes available. Those modes doesn't need to be used for different envieronments, they are just a way that webpack found to apply certain defaults to your build based on the env. If you think that your Q&A should behave (actually it should) like prod, just put it as prod.

TL;TR: mode has nothing to do with env, they are just a way to apply certain defaults to your build.

---

To have access to `process.env.NODE_ENV` on the frontend code, you have to use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I am using mode to change my base URL to my API server what is different in Dev, QA and prod. What should I use instead?

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: Where do I set that?

Comment: I checked my code, and I am using process.env.NODE_ENV  already but does that not get set by the "mode", if so then I can't set a QA flag.

Comment: Yeah, it is not set by mode. you have to add this to when you are running your scripts. You better use cross-env for that: `"build:qa": "cross-env NODE_ENV=Q&A webpack"`. Something like that.

Comment: I get: 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: I see I had to install it, but after installing it and putting it like this: cross-env NODE_ENV=QA webpack --config webpack.prod.js.  I still get  console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV",process.env.NODE_ENV) as production.

Comment: you are doing something wrong somewhere, i did the same thing here on a project i have and i could see env being set to QA.

Comment: ok, I updated my post,to show what I am doing, not sure what else to ad.

Comment: nothing wrong there either. I have 0 clue on what is wrong. Have a look on google on how to setup NODE_ENV.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure why it does not work. I am running it on windows 7, node: v8.10.0. I have made an example on git, maybe seeing the full solution might help. https://github.com/chobo2/webpack-serve-example

Comment: Well, that is something YOU are doing wrong. I did the same thing with your example, and it worked (im using linux, idk about windows...). `WHAT IS ENV??? QA
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/user/webpack-serve-example/dist has been removed.`

Comment: IT got the process.env

Comment: sorry, I am not following what you did.

Comment: That is the point, i did nothing... just put a `console.log("WHAT IS ENV??", process.env.NODE_ENV);` on top of `webpack.prod.js` file.

Comment: hmm, yes I do see that as well, when I put it in production and run "npm run qa". But if you look I have a console.log in Store.js what will say production. I am guessing that the "mode"is overriding the value then. So not sure how to get around that one.

Comment: Nooo, for things inside the code that is transpiled by your webpack, you have to configure the other way...

Comment: What do you mean the other way? as you can see I really don't setup webpack very often, so my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: Hmm, so I put your code in my webpack.common but still in my store.js I am still seeing Production when I run "npm run qa"

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, forgot to add const webpack = require('webpack'), so I just want to confirm, I am still using cross-env and I stuck your code in the common section. I updated my git repo so you can see.